# CloudFormation !Ref not working as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the template below, which describes a new OpsWorks stack. It relies on two roles that already exists in the account, but I need to use a !Ref for the Account Id since this template can generate a stack anywhere.

```
  Stack4:
    Type: AWS::OpsWorks::Stack
    Condition: CreateStack4
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref StackName4
      DefaultOs: 'Amazon Linux 2'
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      DefaultSubnetId: !Ref SubnetId
      UseOpsworksSecurityGroups: True
      CustomCookbooksSource:
        Type: 's3'
        Url: https://oidigital-chef-recipes.s3.amazonaws.com/prd/aws-chef-recipes-master.zip
      ConfigurationManager:
        Name: Chef
        Version: "12"
      DefaultInstanceProfileArn: !Join 
        - ''
        - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
          - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
          - ':role/DefaultOiServerRole'
      ServiceRoleArn: !Join
        - ''
        - - 'arn:aws:iam::'
          - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
          - ':role/aws-opsworks-service-role'
```

For some reason, the !Join declaration in the DefaultInstanceProfileArn is not working as expected. When trying to create a stack, the error below is thrown.

```
Default Instance Profile Arn: must be an instance profile ARN belonging to AWS account
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually an [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) not a role, you're specifying a roles Arn so it is therefore rejecting this.

The console hides that this resource is created, but when you actually attach a role to the instance this is created in the background. If you have attached via the console there will be a instance profile with the same name as the role name already created for you.

The instance profile format is like this `arn:aws:iam::123456789012:instance-profile/Webserver` so ensure your template references this.

If you do not have an instance profile already you can create one in [CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-instanceprofile.html) or [via the CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/create-instance-profile.html).

Comment: You nailed it. I just changed `role` to `instance-profile` in the ARN and it worked, no other changes were needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reference instance profile arn, which should be in format

`arn:aws:iam::1234567890:instance-profile/MyProfile-ASDNSDLKJ` - note the `instance-profile`

The one you supplied is a role arn.